# Mascarar numeração de cartão de crédito

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte numeração:

**4716501731980995**

Preciso dividir ela em 4 partes.
A parte 2/3 deverá ser substituida por **** ****
De que forma eu poderia fazer isto?

Comment: São 16 dígitos, do quinto até o decimo segundo devem virar asteriscos? isso

Comment: pergunta mal formulada. e as outras partes? 4***** ******0995  OU 47***** ******995 etc.. etc...

Comment: Exato Ray, mas acho que alguns podem ter menos né, que é no caso do AmericanExpress

Comment: LeoCaracciolo, pode editar conforme você julga melhor que fique mais esclarecido para os demais, no momento o que eu consegui pensar foi isso.

Comment: vc q tem que dizer a composição das 4 partes, pois a primeira e quarta ficaram sem padão, exemplo, posso ter 1 digito na primeira parte e 4 na ultima, ou 2 na primeira e 3 na ultima, 3 na primeira e 2 na ultima, 4 na primeira e 1 na ultima

Comment: Não, pensa comigo... "Preciso dividir ela em 4 partes. A parte 2/3", isto significa: 16 digitos, / 4 = 4 digitos por partes - ou seja, a 2 e 3 parte contém exatos 4 dígitos, neste caso, devem ser substituidos, conforme o Rray postou.

Comment: Não, a pergunta então deveria ser "Preciso dividir ela em 4 partes" IGUAIS. Só que a parte 2/3 temos 5 asteristicos separados por espaço seguido de 6 asteristicos que contradiz tudo  ***** ******

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A opção mais simples é utilizar a função [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php), [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/225817/91) tem mais detalhes.

Outra alternativa é usar a função [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) para quebrar a string em um array com quatro elementos e contenar o indice zero com a função [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) para gerar os asteriscos e mais o indice três que contem a última parte do cartão.

**[Exemplo - ideone - str_split](https://ideone.com/rw0Xn7)**

```
$str = '4716501731980995';
$novo = str_split($str, 4);
echo $novo[0]. str_repeat('*', 8). $novo[3];
```

Saída:

```
4716********0995
```

Answer (score 8):

Uma outra opção seria utilizar [`substr_replace()`](http://substr_replace), *já que a string não é multibyte não será problema*. Isso não vai quebrar/dividir a string, apenas inserir os asteriscos nos espaços definidos.

```
$string = '4716501731980995';
echo substr_replace($string, ' **** **** ', 4, 8);
```

Resultado:

```
4716 **** **** 0995
```